# Regex for range of numbers with some conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating a project using javascript. I want to implement regex in my project for validation purpose.
Validation is like range of numbers for increasing orders 
Here is my requierments.

```
1-56  --------Pass
15 -----------Pass
1-5-9 --------Fail
asd988 -------Fail

50-49 ------- Fail
```

I am trying using this

```
^[0-9]+-[0-9]+$
```

It is not working for me

Update: A change is user can add multiple values like:

```
1-56,56,3
```

Comment: Looks like it is simpler to do with a bit of code. `var m = /^(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?$/.exec(s)`, then `if (m && !m[2]) { console.log("valid"); } else if (m && Number(m[2]) > Number(m[1])) { console.log("valid"); } else { console.log("invalid"); }`

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks for the help@WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match a string consisting of a single or two numbers, capture the number(s) and compare them if there are two numbers. Only return false if there is no match or if the first number is less than the second:

```js
const rx = /^(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?$/
const isValid = (string) => {
  const m = rx.exec(string);  
  if (m && !m[2]) {
    return true;
  } else if (m && parseInt(m[2], 10) > parseInt(m[1], 10)) {
    return true;
  } else { 
    return false; 
  }
}

const strs = ['1-56,56,3', '1-56', '15', '1-5-9', 'asd988', '50-49'];

for (let s of strs) {
   console.log( s, s.split(",").every(x => isValid(x)) )
   
}
```

The `/^(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?$/` regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `(?:-(\d+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `-` - a `-` char
  - `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
    -`$` - end of string.

Comment: Please help ..I have updated my question @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: When we copy and paste then it gives false: For example: 1025–49151

Comment: @Karan What do you copy/paste? Also, why do you use [EN-DASH](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%E2%80%93#title), **\u2013**, instead of a hyphen? You did not specify your input can contain other types of dashes. Could you please precise? At any rate, you may support common dashes using `/^(\d+)(?:[-–—](\d+))?$/`. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lt0vAi/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Sorry My bad ..Thanks for the help